# Does ExpressionEngine have a way to refer to a static media folder in a template like Django's {{ MEDIA_URL }}?

Tags: php, django, expressionengine

It would be nice to be able to refer to a set "static" folder as a variable instead of having to keep track of a specific URL that might need to be changed if static media gets moved to a CDN later on.

For example, this:

```
<script src="{static_media}/js/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Instead of this:

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just go into the "Template" section of the backend to create a global variable for any other strings you'd like to create a global variable for.

See here: http://expressionengine.com/docs/templates/globals/user_defined.html

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing!

I even named it `{media_url}` as a nod to Django.